# Como quebrar a pagina usando Nreco.PdfGenerator em ASP.NET/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou utilizando CSS para quebrar a página, estou colocando ela dentro de um `<asp:Repeater>` Na primeira quebra tudo ocorre bem porém na terceira página ele quebra incorretamente (no meio da página).

Comment: Pode colocar algum código de exemplo na sua pergunta?